# How to display custom post type tags?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have created custom post type with 'members'

```
 <?php
$member = new CPT(array(
    'post_type_name' => 'members',
    'singular' => __('Members', 'c2s'),
    'plural' => __('Members', 'c2s'),
    'slug' => 'Members'
),
   array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-groups'
));

$member->register_taxonomy(array(
    'taxonomy_name' => 'members_tags',
    'singular' => __('Members Tag', 'c2s'),
    'plural' => __('Members Tags', 'c2s'),
    'slug' => 'member-tag'
));

?>
```

I am trying to print/display members_tags into the individual post. 
[image]

Comment: Possibly using the [WP Custom Post Type Class](https://github.com/jjgrainger/wp-custom-post-type-class) which is now [PostTypes](https://github.com/jjgrainger/PostTypes) by [Joe Grainger](https://github.com/jjgrainger)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get_the_term_list()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) to output a list of links:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'members_tags', '', ',' ); ?>
```

That will output a comma-separated list of links to attached `member_tags`.

If you want the raw tags so you have more control over HTML, use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

```
<?php $member_tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'members_tags' ); ?>
```

Comment: Jacob, 
Thanks for answered. I had solved by same you mentioned, It is good for who are new getting trouble though. I appreciated.